# Pass session from jsp to asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jsp, session

My website login page is in jsp & some of modules in .net ,
So i want pass the session to .aspx page so that access those module

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. Your best bet is passing it as request parameter. If the data is too large to pass as request parameter, then let them share a datasource which JSP and ASP both understands (a SQL database?) so that you can store the session data there along an unique key and finally just pass that unique key around as request parameter so that the one or other can select the data based on the key.

Comment: 0
 
down vote 
accept  Currently I am passing session with request parameter using intermediate page but if I am having password with #(special character),intermediate page stucks..and not able to access other pages without session

Comment: I have a hard time in understanding the "special character" problem. Please elaborate in detail. Did you encode the query parameters?